# "Explore" button disappeared from the SQL Lab of the Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am using Apache Superset version 1.4.1, in my local computer when I run query in SQL editor it shows "Explore" button to view the results of query in chart view whereas the same version when I use in my work computer(Superset hosted on AWS) "Explore" button is disappeared and I can't view my results of query in chart. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The Explore button is only available in case the **Allow this database to be explored** setting is enabled on the **ADVANCED** settings of the DB connection, under **SQL Lab**:

[image: DB configuration on Superset]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I managed to explore it earlier. Thanks again